# Ubuntu IPV6 support

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6

I have a HSPA broadband modem that supports IPV6. Can I use Ubuntu Network Manager to connect using this modem with IPV6.

Comment: Why don't you just try it? :)
If you don't have an installed Ubuntu, you can always use a live version of it.

Comment: I did try. But I cannot connect. It does not prompt an error message either. And I cannot find any option to configure as IPV6.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question to ask your ISP.  Just because the modem supports IPv6 doesn't mean that your ISP will give you an IPv6 address.

Comment: My ISP supports IPV6 and has given me a separate APN also. The problem is I cannot connect with that APN with Ubuntu 10.04.